# Resharper and backstore blank line format

Tags: c#, resharper

The answer to this question is probably a simple No but I am hoping that is not the case.

Is there a way to configure Resharper (v2017.2.2) in such a way that it will format code as follows

```
private int _backingStoreA;
public int PublicMethodA
{
   return this._backingStoreA;
}

private int _backingStoreB;
public int PublicMethodB
{
   return this._backingStoreB;
}
```

The problem I have is that I want a blank line around public properties but don't want a blank line between the public property and it's backing store private field.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is 'No'